# How can I hide the image in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to hide the image in Tkinter Python module. How can I do it?

For example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Example")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(0, 0)

def hide():
   # How can I hide the image?

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

image = PhotoImage(file='example.png')
img = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=image)

hide = Button(root, text="Hide", command=hide)
hide = canvas.create_window(0, 30, anchor=NW, window=hide)

root.mainloop()
```

I try the `[image].destory()`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a canvas object from a canvas, you can use the `delete` method of the canvas. It takes as a parameter the id of the object to be deleted:

```
canvas.delete(img)
```